# Unregister Bower Package that uses BitBucket

Tags: bitbucket, bower, package-managers

So I registered a package with Bower, `sugar-mixins` and I was using BitBucket as my repo. It seems that was a bad idea. When I run `bower unregister sugar-mixins` it cannot remove it from the Bower registry since its not a GitHub hosted library.

Any thoughts on how I can remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening an issue on https://github.com/bower/registry allows for packages to be removed.